# Accuracy and Loss - Train vs Validation

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am doing a DL experiment with Point Cloud dataset.
I am using cross entropy loss and calculating accuracy as shown below

```
loss = F.cross_entropy(logits, labels)
acc = (torch.argmax(logits, dim=1) == labels).float().mean()
```

I am getting following Loss and Accuracy Plots after ~20 epochs of training.
[image: Loss]
[image: Accuracy]
[image: Loss and Accuracy together]

I can observe that exactly after 7th epoch(can be seen from the 3rd figure), the Train and Validation curves cross each other(for both Loss and Accuracy) and drift apart. I believe there's overfitting happening. Can someone suggest any other issues and possible solutions?

Thank you!

Comment: A general suggestion - make training more difficult for the model. It's usually done with augmentations / dropout / decreasing size of layers and other techniques, application of which highly depends on your exact task, architecture, dataset

Comment: It's recently became popular to use Batch Norm between most of layers - helps to both training and validation

Comment: I am using data augmentations for my training sample. I do have batchNorm2d after every conv2d layer as well. Regarding decreasing layer size, Should I be reducing the feature size of the layer and increase the number of layers?

Comment: Always check one change at a time to make reasonable conclusions. Try first decreasing number of channels without changing the number of layers.

Comment: You can also make augmentations more difficult like high noise / warping / deletion of many points